# Stay on the same window after submitting form via JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
if(Client is selected) 
{
//then show related projects
}
else 
{
//Don't show anything
}
```

Now, if I select a client, all project related to that client will be dispalyed, and in front of each project, there is a button. When I click on it, a JQuery dialog box shows up in order to update project information.
It's ok until now, when I update the project details, the second condition of the above **if** starts and nothing is displayed.
My manager doesn't like this because he prefers that the window stays as it is after update.

Any suggestions?
Bests.

Comment: What does "submit via jQuery" mean? Are you using Ajax?

Comment: No I'm not, I use JQuery to display a dialog box containing a form with data to be updated

Comment: you can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ first serialize the form data with http://api.jquery.com/serialize/  (see also the examples in these pages)

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to call a PHP script if you want to stay on the same page.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: don't use w3schools it is not fully correct and information there may mislead you.

Comment: I agree @bansi :)
However, I think using Ajax is the key